# Trying to divide two doubles and but result is wrong in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, numbers, division

The number type is double. I have checked that:
331.83319305/884.8885148=0.375

but vb.net gives an answer of 0.37499999999999994.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should do some reading on how floating point numbers work. This is par for the course and the very reason that you should always work with a specific number of significant figures when displaying arithmetic results.

Comment: If you look at the value of 884.8885148, you will find it gets approximated to 884.8885148000000526735675521194934844970703125. There is an explanation at  [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: It is most certainly related to how your language (vb.net) handles double precision numbers. You'll see that with most programming languages there is a rounding error when using floating point algebra.